# Haskell class instance

Tags: haskell

It's my first exercise to understand the classes in Haskell. My problem is how to define the functions that I have declared in the class and how to test them by terminal ghci.

I explain step by step what I did:

```
type Point2d = (Int, Int)   -- point
type Vector2d = (Int, Int)   -- vector

data Shape = 
    Line       Point2d Point2d
    | Triangle Point2d Point2d Point2d
    deriving (Eq, Show)

class ClassShape s where
    name    :: s -> String
    perim   :: s -> Int               -- given a CShape calculates the perimeter
    move    :: s -> Vector2d -> s
```

Now, I declare `s` as ClassShape instance, by implementing the corresponding functions.

```
nameShape :: Shape s -> String
nameShape Line = "Line"
nameShape Triangle = "Triangle"

perimShape :: Shape s -> Int
perimShape Line a b = 999 -- ...
perimShape Triangle a b c = 999 -- ...
```

Here's my problem: how should I declare the functions? I just need to see an "example" to understand the concept.

The error that Haskell returns is:

```
`Shape' is applied to too many type arguments
In the type signature for `nameShape':
  nameShape :: Shape s -> String


`Shape' is applied to too many type arguments
In the type signature for `perimShape':
  perimShape :: Shape s -> Int
```

Then, how do I test the program on Haskell?

Thanks to all.

Comment: just as a remark: right now your `ClassShape` is not too useful, as `nameShape`, ... will serve just the same purpose as `name` (inside the class)

Comment: Will there ever be another instance for that class? AFAICS, not. In such case, you should remove it. The code so far looks to be a straight adaptation from OOP, which is pretty much an antipattern in Haskell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that `nameShape` function will not work, because there is no `Shape s` type defined. Remember that `s` is a type variable. Only if  you have defined `Shape s` type constructor you can use them. You have defined `Shape` type in your definition but not `Shape s`. For defining instance of typeclass, you have to do something like this:

```
instance ClassShape Shape where
    name (Line _ _) = "Line"
    name (Triangle _ _ _) = "Triangle"
    perim (Line x y) = undefined -- Calculate perimiter using x and y
    perim (Triangle x y z) = undefined
    move (Line x y) = undefined
    move (Triangle x y z) = undefined
```

You have to fill the `undefined` with working parts.

Answer (score 1):

You're making a common confusion of early Haskell programmers: using two different things which work in related ways (sum types and classes) to do the same thing in two different ways. Thus there are two problems: the "little" problem (what does this error mean?) and the "big" problem (why is your code shaped like this?).

### The Little Problem

You wrote `Shape s` when you meant to just write `Shape`. The way you have defined `Shape`, it has kind `*` (that is, it is a concrete type) rather than kind `* -> *`, which is the kind of *adjectives* -- things like "a list of" or "a pair of" which are abstract until you give them a concrete type to modify ("a list of strings" is concrete, "a list of" is abstract). When you write `Shape s` you are applying `Shape` as an adjective to a type variable `s` but it's not an adjective; it's a noun.

That is why you get the error:

```
`Shape' is applied to too many type arguments
```

Side note: you may be used to languages where the error message usually is not very well-related to the actual problem. In Haskell usually the compiler tells you exactly what is wrong, as it did in this case.

### The Big Problem

Type classes are collections of unrelated types which can do the same things. The type class syntax passes an implicit context as a "constraint", this context can be implicit because it belongs to the type.

You may need to read that last paragraph a few times in a quiet corner. Basically I mean to say that you can do the same thing as a type class with a data constructor for the context:

```
data EqOrd s = EqOrdLib {getEq :: s -> s -> Bool, getCmp :: s -> s -> Ordering}

-- this is just provided to us as a primitive by Haskell
intEOL :: EqOrd Int
intEOL = EqOrdLib (==) compare

-- but we can then define things like this:
listEOL :: EqOrd x -> EqOrd [x]
listEOL (EqOrdLib base_eq base_cmp) = EqOrdLib list_eq list_cmp where
    list_cmp [] [] = EQ
    list_cmp (_:_) [] = GT
    list_cmp [] (_:_) = LT
    list_cmp (x:xs) (y:ys) = case base_cmp x y of
        LT -> LT
        GT -> GT
        EQ -> list_cmp xs ys
    list_eq xs ys = list_cmp xs ys == EQ
```

Now to use that sort of context, you would have to write explicitly:

```
quicksort :: EqOrd x -> [x] -> [x]
quicksort _ [] = []
quicksort lib (p:els) = quicksort lib lesser ++ [p] ++ quicksort lib greater
    where cmp = getCmp lib
          p_less_than x = cmp x p == LT
          p_gte x = not . p_less_than
          greater = filter p_less_than els
          lesser = filter p_gte els
```

See, we explicitly pass in this library of functions `lib` and explicitly pull out the comparison function `cmp = getCmp lib`.

Type classes allow us to *implicitly* pass the library of functions, by stating up-front that the type itself only has one such library. We pass the library as a "constraint", so instead of `EqOrd x -> [x] -> [x]` you write `Ord x => [x] -> [x]` with the "fat arrow" of constraints. But secretly it means "when you ask me to use the `<` function on two values of type `x`, I know implicitly what library to get that function from and will get that function for you."

Now: you have **one type**, `Shape`, so **you don't need typeclasses**. (Go back to the first paragraph above: *Type classes are collections of unrelated types which can do the same things.*

If you want to do type classes then instead of the sum-type for Shape, let's define n-dimensional vectors of different types:

```
class Vector v where
    (*.) :: (Num r) => r -> v r -> v r
    (.+.) :: (Num r) => v r -> v r -> v r
    norm :: (Num r, Floating r) => v r -> r
    -- another advantage of type classes is *default declarations* like: 
    (.-.) :: (Num r) => v r -> v r -> v r
    v1 .-. v2 = v1 .+. (-1 *. v2)

data V2D r = V2D r r deriving (Eq, Show)
instance Vector V2D where
    s *. V2D x y = V2D (s * x) (s * y)
    V2D x1 y1 .+. V2D x2 y2 = V2D (x1 + x2) (y1 + y2)
    norm (V2D x y) = sqrt (x^2 + y^2)

data V3D r = V3D r r r deriving (Eq, Show)
instance Vector V3D where
    s *. V3D x y z = V3D (s * x) (s * y) (s * z)
    V3D x1 y1 z1 .+. V3D x2 y2 z2 = V3D (x1 + x2) (y1 + y2) (z1 + z2)
    norm (V3D x y z) = sqrt (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)
```

Then we can write things like:

```
newtype GeneralPolygon v r = Poly [v r] 

perimeter :: (Num r, Floating r, Vector v) -> GeneralPolygon v r -> r
perimeter (Poly []) = 0
perimeter (Poly (x : xs)) = foldr (+) 0 (map norm (zipWith (.-.) (x : xs) (xs ++ [x])))

translate :: (Vector v, Num r) => GeneralPolygon v r -> v r -> GeneralPolygon v r
translate (Poly xs) v = Poly (map (v .+.) xs)
```

### Making Typeclasses Work For You

Now if you really want to, you can *also* unwrap your sum-type data declaration into a bunch of data declarations:

```
data Line = Line Point2d Point2d deriving (Eq, Show)
data Square = Square Point2d Point2d deriving (Eq, Show)
data Triangle = Triangle Point2d Point2d Point2d deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Now you can do something simple like:

```
class Shape s where
    perim :: s -> Int
    move  :: s -> Vector2d -> s
```

Although I should say, you'll run into a problem when you want to do square roots for perimeters (`sqrt` is in the `Floating` typeclass, which `Int` does not have functions for, you'll want to change Int to Double or something).